# Finding the sum of the coefficient squared of a polynomial

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

Given a polynomial

$$f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n a_kx^n = a_0+a_1x+ \ldots + a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_nx^n $$

is it possible to find a general expression for

$$ \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k^2 ?$$

For example, $\sum_{k = 0}^n a_k = f(1)$. The motivation for asking this is to arrive at alternate proofs of identities like $$\dbinom{2p}p = \sum_{k = 0}^p \dbinom{p}k ^2 \equiv 2 \pmod {p^3}$$ for prime $p$.

Comment: The only i can think at the moment is simple algebraic manipulation. But I don't know if that's any useful.

$\sum_{k = 0}^n a_k^2=(\sum_{k = 0}^n a_k)^2-\sum_{i=0}^n  \sum_{j=0}^na_ia_j$  , where $i\neq j$

Comment: I think, you should try using binomial theorem for $(1+x)^n$ Then take it's square both side and compare the terms. This should do the first equality.